# Is it possible to accelerate even more Google maps for Flash with Stage 3D hardrware acceleration?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am using Google Flash API for Flash and so far it is working more than great.

Anyway I wish to increase it's drawing performance using Stage 3D hardware acceleration.

- Is it possible to force hardware acceleration using Stage 3D with Google Maps API for Flash ?

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but the Google Maps Flash API has been deprecated.

Comment: The google maps api was developed using the normal stage and not stage3d. I think there is no way you can achieve that.

Comment: RIAstar - our developers start investigating Google Maps alternatives, after deprecation of Flash API, and so far we are probably switching to BING/OSM flash based API's, but until the transition is complete, we are looking for something to accelerate the increased speed demands. Since there is not even closer to Flash API productive alternative, we are counting on it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to force Stage3D acceleration on any existing content.

Apps need to be built specifically for the GPU using the Stage3D API's directly or working on top of a framework. Geometry is composed of triangles defined by a series of vertices, these vertices are essentially colored and assembled by shaders written in AS3's shader assembly language AGAL. Vector content cannot be rendered on the GPU, everything is bitmap based.

This is a great post on how Stage3D is implemented: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html

Also as RIAstar mentioned, the Google maps Flash API is deprecated. Mapquest has a Flash API that might be worth checking out. I'm not sure how the performance compares since it is not a Stage3D app either.

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash

Comment: We are currently investigating the other Flash/Flex alternatives.
So far - OpenScales and MapQuest is our prime targets, but I am really interested still in Google Maps regardless their strange deprecation annonce.

Answer (score 1):

[YCanvas](https://github.com/jozefchutka/YCanvas) is an open source 2D tile renderer library written in ActionScript 3. It provides high performance solution for rendering world maps. The library also contains Stage3D (GPU) accelerated implementation based on Starling.

[ApplicationMap](http://ycanvas.yoz.sk/maps/) - YCanvasMap implementation with Feathers UI available on  (available tiles: ArcGIS Imagery, ArcGIS National Geographic, MapQuest, OpenStreetMap, MapBox, CloudMade, Bing Maps Imagery)

Comment: Jozef Chutka - the library You are working on is more than awesome, I am really exited to see the further developments with Polylines, Markers and Regions simplified as the Google Maps API for Flash is.